# Limit length of each element present in an array in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a requirement where I have an input field. In that input field I am passing string value seperated by commas. I am storing each input value in array. I want to restrict user from entering more than 4 characters.

For example: Suppose we have this input

```
["mango","papaya","jackfruit"]
```

I want like

```
["mang","papa","jack"]
```

I want that when someone enters more than 4 character it wont allow user to enter anything thereafter. If he presses comma then he is allow to write another string value of 4 character

*component.html*

```
<input formControlName="name" (keypress)="singleElement($event)" (input)="inputName($event)">
```

*component.ts*

```
inputName(event){

 this.value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value    
}


singleElement(event) {
 return(
 (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) ||
 (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) ||
 (event.charCode > 47 && event.charCode < 58) ||
 event.charCode == 44
 )}
```

Comment: Just use `slice`: `this.value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value.slice(0, 4)`  Don't bother about blocking the user from inputting. That is user unfriendly. You don't want them to think their keyboard is malfunctioning.

Comment: @trincot I cannot use slice as the input which user going to enter is valid 4 characters input. I can display an error message if user enters more than 4 character but I need to block user from inputting.

Comment: *"but I need to block user from inputting"*: bad design.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
});
previousValue = '';
@ViewChild('myTags') tags!: ElementRef;

inputName(event: any) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const tags = value.split(',');
  if (tags.some((t: any) => t.length > 4)) {
    const caretPosition = this.tags.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    this.form.patchValue({ name: this.previousValue });
    this.tags.nativeElement.selectionStart =
      this.tags.nativeElement.selectionEnd = caretPosition - 1;
    return;
  }
  this.previousValue = value;
}
```

When the input field is updated it checks if any of the max-four character tags is longer than 4. If so, it replaces the form field with the previous value and sets caret to the previous position (otherwise it would jump to the end of the string).

Check this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-quyczz?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the above, you can use the 'maxlenght' attribute in your input tag

Syntax:
`<input maxlength="number">`
Behaviour: It won't take input values after the stated maxlenght which in your case should be 4. So, user can't enter more than 4 characters in the input field.

More details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

**You can try something like the below:**

```js
class Component {
inputValue = '';
    constructor() {
  }
  inputHandler(event){
    if (event.key === ','){//I don't if this works you'll need to check
      const input = document.getElementById('input');
      input.maxlenght += 5; //add the lenght for the ; and new 4 characters
      input.value += ',';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<input id='input' (keypress)="inputHandler($event)" maxlenght='4' [(ngModel)]='inputValue'>
```

**I don't know if this will work, you'll need to check and play around this to find out.**

Else if you want, you can collect a 4 charactered string from the user; when they submit clear the input and ask them to enter another.

Though, I won't recommend the above solutions. Alternatively, you can add a note for the user about this; collect the whole input and then process it to suit your use case.

For Example:

```js
const inputValue = 'mango,banana,apple';
const elements = inputValue.split(',');
const result = elements.map((ele)=> ele.slice(0,4));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for a [custom formControl validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). Something like this

```html
const fixedLength: ValidatorFn = (
  control: AbstractControl,
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const value: string = control.value;
  if (value.length) {
    const values = value.split(',');
    return values.some((v) => v.length > 4)
      ? { length: 'should be 4 chars max' }
      : null;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Then you attach this validator to your form control and display the error message to the user if it is detected.

In any case, it is not a good idea to block or disable the input, what if a user copy-paste the input? You disable the submit button and display the error state letting your user correct the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your code a bit.

```
<input formControlName="name" (input)="inputName($event)">
```

And for ts file :

```
value: string = '';

  inputName(event: any) {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    const values = inputValue.split(',');

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      values[i] = values[i].substring(0, 4);
    }

    this.value = values.join(',');
  }
```

This should work as per your requirements. Do let me know how it goes.